# Get date from monday depending on week number

Tags: php, date, numbers, week-number

I can`t figure out the code to get the date from monday depending on the week number of this year.

could someone help me with this code?

thanks.

Comment: Clarify what you need. Show some code you've already tried.

Comment: Can you edit the question and make it clear what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please also include attempted code and expected output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will provide the Monday of a certain week this year:

```
$thisYear = date('Y');
$weekNum = 40;

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$thisYear-W$weekNum-1"));  // Outputs 2013-09-30
```

Comment: Yeah I like this one more than mine. The flexibility of strtotime amazes me every time I see it used a new way.

Comment: I can't remember where I found it, but it comes in handy when trying to compare information from a Mon-Sun week of this year to the same Mon-Sun week of last year.

Comment: If you are using this code, be carefull with week number, it must be two digit long; always prepend 0 if week number is bellow 10.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class :

```php
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->setISODate($year, $week);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/89881)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

I have this laying around (I'm not sure if I or someone else was the original author) but give it a try:

```
  $week = 34; //Enter your week here.

  $week = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  2013 ) + ( $week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ); 

  $monday = $week - 86400 * ( date( 'N', $week ) - 1 );
  $monday = date( 'Y-m-d', $monday );

  echo $monday;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, week=40 returns `2013-10-07`, but it should `2013-09-30`.