# Get the date of monday of a given week

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to get the date of a monday of a given week. I found some examples on here, but all of them are not working.

This is what I have currently.

```
$week = $_GET['week'];
$year = date('Y');

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$year-W$week-1"));
echo $date;
```

How would I do this?

Comment: is this a typo here on stackoverflow or it's in your original code too? strtotime("$year-W$week-1")   **W$week**

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio http://stackoverflow.com/a/18599506/2215807

Comment: Works for me: `$year = 2015; $week = 39; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$year-W$week-1"));
echo '<br/><br/>' . $date;` Gives me 2015-09-21 which is yesterday.

Comment: The obvious question is: What are you putting inside `$_GET['week']`???  It should be a number from 1 to 52.

Comment: @developerwjk a number between 1 and 52, but all the result are giving me 1970-01-01

Comment: I'm willing to bet that `$_GET['week']` is "1" instead of "01" (or other single digit) and set as a string. var_dump will ya? ;-) I.e.:  `$_GET['week']=1;` rather than  `$_GET['week']="01";` or gets parsed as `$_GET['week']=01;` and the leading zero is treated as an octal.

Comment: *"a number between 1 and 52"* - it needs to be in 01,02....09 format and as a string. I think I'm right about this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- damm, I never though about it being seen as a string. It works fine now. Thanks

Comment: hehehe you're welcome. So..want that as an answer? ;-)

Comment: oh crap.. the answer's been closed.

Comment: 01 works but 1 doesn't work. Changed my script client side to request 01, 02, 03 etc instead of it requesting. Not the best fix, but it works.

Comment: that's what is important, *cheers* glad to have been of help.